Can Diffusion Models denoise an unseen probability distribution during inference?
I am trying to understand if it is possible to condition the reverse condition process with a weight tensor. Normally this weight tensor is more restrictive (binary) and could be used for downstream tasks like inpainting. In regions where weight=1 then we add the output of the model and in regions where weight=0 we add the initial image corrupted with noise.
In my case, I want to relax the binary condition to values in $[0,1]$. Let's denote the initial image as $i_0$ and the denoising model as $f$. At timestep $t$, during the reverse process, we blend the corrupted input $i_{t-1}$ and the model output $f(x_t)$ as:
$$x_{t-1} = (1-w) \cdot i_{t-1} + w \cdot f(x_t)$$
For binary weight masks this is OK, because the model has seen noise samples from both the distribution of $i_{t-1}$ and the distribution of $f(x_t)$. However, when the mask is non-binary then, the linear combination of two gaussians end up in a new gaussian:
$$G = \mathcal{N}((1-w)\cdot\mu_i + w\cdot\mu_f, (1-w)^2\cdot\sigma_i^2+w^2\cdot\sigma_f^2)$$
where  $\mu_i, \sigma_i$ and $\mu_f, \sigma_f$ are the parameters of the distributions of the corrupted initial image and the reverse diffusion process respectively.
Unfortunately, I am not having good results if I sample $x_{t-1} \sim G$. Is this because $G$ is not a known distribution for $f$ to denoise? Or is my intuition on this problem wrong?
Thanks!
